# Narrowing argument types based on overload variants in MyPy

Tags: python, mypy

I have the following code, for which I have no idea how to avoid the issue with narrowing down function arguments based on function's overload variants:

```
from typing import Union
from typing import Callable
from typing import overload

class A:
    pass

class B:
    pass

class C:
    pass

class D:
    pass

@overload
def f(x: A) -> C:...

@overload
def f(x: B) -> D:...

def f(x: Union[A, B]) -> Union[C, D]:
    if isinstance(x, A):
        return C()
    else:
        return D()

@overload
def g(x: A, func: Callable[[C], bool]) -> None:...

@overload
def g(x: B, func: Callable[[D], bool]) -> None:...

def g(x: Union[A, B], func: Union[Callable[[C], bool], Callable[[D], bool]]) -> None:
    obj = f(x)
    func(obj)
```

The code results in the following error message:

```
test.py:37: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "Union[C, D]"; expected "C"
test.py:37: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "Union[C, D]"; expected "D"
```

Is there a way to overcome this issue with MyPy not being able to narrow down argument types based on the overload variants?

Comment: Overloads are intended to increase type granularity, not fix malformed signatures in the first place. Your `f` signature is still valid without the overloads, so that's why the overloads can be added. Your `g` signature is invalid regardless (because you take two `Union`s where `x` could have `A` selected and `func` could have `Callable[[D], bool]` selected), so overloads will also be invalid. Could you dive into your usecase a bit more? Might be able to solve it with `TypeVar`.

Comment: @MarioIshac The use case is that I have request processing function which similar to `g` takes a class `x` as it's argument, it uses that class and another function similar to `f` to produce an object of a type which depends on the input class. This function `f` also takes another function as it's argument similar to `func` which is used to process the result of a call to `f` inside `g`, the type of the argument that `func` takes depends on the type of `x`, i.e. if `x` is `A` and `g` always converts `A` to `C`, then `func` should take `C` as it's argument, which is ensured by the overloads.

Comment: @MarioIshac So, my main issue is how to correctly annotate `f` for the above use case.

Comment: @MarioIshac Not sure what do you mean by  overloads of `g` being invalid - MyPy correctly flags as error any code that calls `g` with `x` being `A` and `func` being a function that takes `D` as an argument.